# Does Eddystone protocol is supported in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on a project where I need to deal with Eddystone protocol in Raspberry Pi, So my question is, Can we implement Eddystone protocol in Raspberry Pi?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, with, for example, bleno

Comment: @MikePetrichenko can I able to connect to sensor and configure advertisement interval, I mean can I write data to characteristic

Comment: All is in your hands. You can write more or less any application on RPI.